# Choosing C so that c1Y1+c2Y2 is an Unbiased Estimator of Θ

Tags: statistics

Let *Y1* and *Y2* be two unbiased estimators of Θ let *Var(Y1)*= *4Var(Y2)* and the correlation coefficient between *Y1* and *Y2* be -.5 find constants *c1* and *c2* such that *c1Y1* + *c2Y2* is an unbiased estimator of Θ and has the smallest variance among all other linear combinations of *Y1* and *Y2* that are unbiased for Θ.

All I have so far is that CovY1Y2/√(4VarY2*VarY2) = CovY1Y2/2VarY2=-.5 (equation/definition of correlation coefficient)... I have no idea what to do next or even if this is a necessary step towards solving the problem. How would I know Y1+Y2 is an unbiased estimator of Θ?

Comment: Please make use of MathJax

Comment: $Y_1+Y_2$ is most of the time not an unbiased estimator of $\Theta$. If $\Theta\ne 0$ then $c_1Y_1+c_2Y_2$ is an unbiased estimator if and only if $c_2=1-c_1$.

Answer (score 1):

In general, as mentioned in a comment, $c_1Y_1+c_2Y_2$ is an unbiased estimator of $\Theta$ if and only if $c_2=1-c_1$. For $E(c_1Y_1+c_2Y_2)=c_1E(Y_1)+c_2E(Y_2)=(c_1+c_2)\Theta$. If $\Theta\ne 0$, this is equal to $\Theta$ if and only if $c_1+c_2=1$.

Let $\sigma^2$ be the variance of $Y_2$. Then $Y_1$ has variance $4\sigma^2$.

We find the variance of $c_1Y_1+c_2Y_2$. By a general formula you may be familiar with, we have 
$$\text{Var}(c_1Y_1+c_2Y_2)=c_1^2\text{Var}(Y_1)+c_2^2\text{Var}(Y_2)+2c_1c_2\text{Cov}(Y_1,Y_2).\tag{1}$$
You know how to find $\text{Cov}(Y_1,Y_2)$ in terms of $\sigma^2$.

Let $c_1=t$. Then $x_2=1-t$. Write down the right-hand side of (1) in terms of $t$ and $\sigma^2$. You will get a *quadratic* in $t$. Choose the value of $t$ that minimizes this quadratic.  That can be done in one of the usual ways, completing the square or differentiating.

Comment: Can I not solve for the quadratic using C1 and C2 then substituting after?

Comment: actually I'm still confused about how to solve this quadratic or how to set it up.

Comment: I will write down some detail. It may take more than one comment. By a calculation you probably know how to make, the Cov of $(Y_1,Y_2)$ divided by $\sqrt{\text{Var}(Y_1)\text{Var}(Y_2)}$ is $-0.5$, so $\text{Cov}(Y_1,Y_2)=(2\sigma^2)(-0.5)=-\sigma^2$. Substitute in (1), using $t=c_1$. We get $t^2\sigma^2+4(1-t)^2\sigma^2-2t(1-t)\sigma^2$. (More)

Comment: @ShingHeliosHan: We want to minimize the above expression. Expand. So we want to minimize $7t^2-10t+4$. By calculus the minimum is reached at $t=\frac{10}{14}$. That gives $c_1=\frac{10}{14}$ and therefore $c_2=\frac{4}{14}$. I am writing this quickly, and morning coffee has not yet kicked in, so there may be an arithmetical error along the way. Please verify details.

Answer (score 0):

You have $E(Y_1) = \Theta$ and $E(Y_2) = \Theta$ from the unbiasedness assumption.

$c_1 Y_1 +c_2 Y_2$ is an unbiased estimator or the parameter if $E(c_1 Y_1 +c_2 Y_2) = \Theta$.

Hence, $c_1$ and $c_2$ must satisfy:

$E(c_1 Y_1 +c_2 Y_2) = E(Y_1)$

$E(c_1 Y_1 +c_2 Y_2) = E(Y_2)$

which by linearity of $E$ yields

$c_1 E(Y_1) +c_2 E(Y_2) = E(Y_1)$

$c_1 E(Y_1) +c_2 E(Y_2) = E(Y_2)$

where $E(Y_1) = E(Y_2) = \Theta$, hence you get only one equation which does not identify $c_1$ and $c_2$

$c_2  = (1-c_1)$

Therefore, any pair $(c_1,c_2)$ satisfying $c_1 = (1-c_2)$ will give you an unbiased estimator. Now you have to find the combination satisfying this equation that gives you the smallest variance. How do you do that?

Consider to minimize $Var(c_1 Y_1 +(1-c_1) Y_2)$ with respect to $c_1$. It should be relatively easy.

Note: Check if the expression is convex in $c_1$. If so, the argmin is characterized by the first-order condition.

Comment: do you minimize by taking the derivative then solving for 0? and the minimal point is the smaller one?

Comment: Taking the derivative gives you the first-order condition (FOC). If the sufficient condition is satisfied (i.e. the second derivative is strictly positive), the objective function is strictly convex in $c$. Therefore, the FOC characterizes the unique minimum.